Can't get antialiasing in some PyQt6 widgets while if was working with PyQt5
I recently modify my own made movie manager from PyQt5 to PyQt6 cause I had some trouble with PIL.
I lost antialiasing in the main grid while it remains on the displaypanel ( at the bottom ).

Some relevant (I guess) code, the widget used in the main grid ( a QTableWidget ):
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageQt
from settings import *
import subprocess
import os

class zImageWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem):

    def __init__(self, dic):

        super().__init__()
        self.dic = dic
        self.path = dic['path']
        self.changeIcon(dic['icon'])

    def changeIcon(self, icon_path):

        a_icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        a_pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.dic['icon'])        
        a_icon.addPixmap(a_pixmap, QtGui.QIcon.Mode.Selected, QtGui.QIcon.State.Off)
        self.setIcon(a_icon)


    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):

        '''Launches the movie associated with currentItem in PLAYER.
        os.startfile(path) doesn't work with UNC paths'''

        if os.path.isfile( self.dic['path'] ):
            subprocess.Popen([PLAYER, self.dic['path']])

I'm no way expert, just a hobby programmer.
I Can provide more code on demand.
Thanks for any clue.
I tried several things, nothing worked, not sure at which level I should work (app, TableWidget, TableWidgetItem, Painter ...)
print(QtCore.qVersion()) gives 6.7.2
Operating System: Manjaro Linux
Kernel: Linux 6.6.47-1-MANJARO
Architecture: x86-64

I cannot reproduce this with PyQt6.6 on linux, but it would help to know more about your configuration: specific Qt (not PyQt!) version, OS and possible HighDPI configuration. Note that you don't normally need to create a QPixmap for a QIcon (just use QIcon(<path>)), and you can actually directly set a QPixmap as decoration role (self.setData(Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole, pixmap)). For a visualization like this you should also consider using QListWidget, which supports displaying items in "icon mode" (laying items horizontally, with line wrapping).

Thanks. Infos added to main. I tried :

        self.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(icon_path))
        self.setData(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole, self.icon().pixmap)

but get no images at all

Please provide a proper [mre]. We need a fully working test-case which shows that the same image is rendered differently in a QTableWidget compared with whatever other widget you are using in the panel at the bottom.

@jackclash Calling setData() with the decoration is obviously mutually exclusive with setIcon(), and your attempt doesn't make any sense: 1. you already have a QPixmap (a_pixmap) and therefore you don't need a QIcon if you're using it; self.icon.pixmap is a reference to a function. Please read the suggestions given to you more carefully, and also check the documentation. Then, as asked above, provide a proper MRE.

Finaly I ended up following the QListWidget recommendation. And it was a good one : images rendering works well, antialiased as expected. It even allowed me to tremendously simplify my code where I was managing rows and columns by hand.
So i'm happy for now. Thanks for the tips.
